# Method toString cannot be applied to given types error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to learn Android by creating a calculator app. I have buttons with Ids `button0` to `button9`. On clicking the button, their value should be be added to textViewAbove but I can't seem to be able to convert an integer into a string. I feel that the Android studio is taking my `toString()` method to be of `integer.toString()` type.

Code:

```
int[] buttonId = {R.id.button0, R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3, R.id.button4,
        R.id.button5, R.id.button6, R.id.button7, R.id.button8, R.id.button9};


Button[] bt = new Button[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {       //If this doesn't work then do it separately.
    final int I = i;
    bt[I] = (Button) findViewById(buttonId[I]);

    bt[I].setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    textViewAbove.append(toString(I));
                    //Enter action methods here.
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Error:

```
Error:(111, 50) error: method toString in class Object cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Note that the code is inside the `onCreate` method in the `MainActivity` class.

Comment: Where is your `toString` method

Comment: You don't need this `final int I = i;`

Comment: @3kings This statement- `textViewAbove.append(toString(I));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FindViewById where ID is dynamic string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056817/findviewbyid-where-id-is-dynamic-string)

Comment: @MuratK. I hadn't done that initially but some error popped up about accessing outer class elements without final.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are attempting to invoke the method `String toString()` of the anonymous subclass of `Button.OnClickListener`. This method takes no parameters, so it is complaining when you try to give it an `int` parameter.

You should invoke some other `toString` method which does accept an `int` (or `Integer`) parameter, e.g. `Integer.toString(int)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Integer.toString(I);`

Answer (score 1):

The `toString` method, which is inherited from the `Object` class, does not take any arguments.

Instead, you can use implicit conversion like `textViewAbove.append(""+I);`
Or more favorably the `textViewAbove.append(String.valueOf(I));`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `int I` with

```
final String I = i +"";
```

and remove the `toString()` method and simply use

```
textViewAbove.append(I);
```